# How health check of Kubernetes work with Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, servicemesh, istio-sidecar

I am doing with k8s and Istio as service meshing. I wonder what if pod in a service A is not ready(Readiness is unhealthy), How Istio will treat this pod? Is there way i can config rule of load balance(Load balance at L3/L4 layer)?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check [Health Checking of Istio Services](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/mesh/app-health-check/) to check the health of your pods. As mentioned in the post, you would have to configure the containers with [liveness probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) using kubectl before you can actually do health checking.

Comment: I've read this document. But in this [document](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/)  said: _"By default, the Envoy proxies distribute traffic across each service’s load balancing pool using a round-robin model, where requests are sent to each pool member in turn, returning to the top of the pool once each service instance has received a request"_. Istio will remove **unhealthy pod** to Load Balancing pool. But long live connection(TCP, gRPC) will be still keep?

Comment: I've tested this case. Long live connection still keeping. But i wonder how Istio can do it?

Comment: I read that document several time but I must say it is very poorly documented till date. Its starts with top level concept without explaining what are Rewrite Probes. Why HTTP probes need to be rewritten. Woo rewrites HTTP probes ?